# Error PostgreSQL delete with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

## Postgres 8.4

```
DELETE
FROM processing_transaction AS pt 
INNER JOIN processing_transaction_movement AS ptm 
ON pt.processing_transaction_id = ptm.processing_transaction_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_package tesp ON pt.test_package_id = tesp.test_package_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_batch tbat On tesp.test_batch_id = tbat.test_batch_id
WHERE pt.processing_transaction_type = 'TEST';
```

I get following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at >>INNER<<
> LINE 1: DELETE FROM processing_transaction AS pt INNER JOIN processi...

Please could you help me to find the error in my SQL-query

---

Thank you for your support @desislavkamenov @jan.
Now I used this:

> BEGIN WORK;
>
> DELETE
> FROM processing_transaction AS pt
> USING processing_transaction_movement AS ptm, test_package tesp, test_batch tbat
> WHERE pt.processing_transaction_type = 'TEST';
> AND pt.processing_transaction_id = ptm.processing_transaction_id
> AND pt.test_package_id = tesp.test_package_id
> AND tesp.test_batch_id = tbat.test_batch_id
>
> ROLLBACK;

But I need to delete data from two tables **(processing_transaction and processing_transaction_movement)** , I have looking for somethink like that and found out that I can do it with "ON DELETE CASCADE". But I don´t know how to use this here.
So Please help me again.

Comment: Ummmm...your `delete` statement is nonsensical, as you haven't specified the table from which you'd like to delete rows.

Comment: I don;t know postgres but in SQl Server you shoudl put the alias for the table you are deleting from after the word delete. It doesn't know which table to delete from.

Comment: If you have foreign keys on the other tables when you delete from the main table it will automatically cascade and delete records.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use JOIN in DELETE statement. Instead use USING and put the second table there.
Something like this should work (sorry but i can't test it, so run it after `BEGIN`ing a transaction and check the results if they are what you expect before `COMMIT`ting it; `ROLLBACK` if they aren't).

```
DELETE
FROM processing_transaction AS pt 
USING processing_transaction_movement AS ptm, test_package tesp, test_batch tbat 
WHERE pt.processing_transaction_type = 'TEST'
AND pt.processing_transaction_id = ptm.processing_transaction_id
AND pt.test_package_id = tesp.test_package_id
AND tesp.test_batch_id = tbat.test_batch_id
```

Here is a link to the documentation.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Comment: I used this example to form my own query, and it took the `;` as the end of the statement and deleted the whole table.  That sucked.  Why is that `;` there?

Comment: You are right, it was a typo and i removed the ; from the query.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't copy/paste code for this reason. Additionally, you can wrap your query in BEGIN and roll it back or commit it optionally: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-begin.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `JOIN` syntax isn't supported in `DELETE` statements. According to the [documentation for DELETE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-delete.html), you can use certain kinds of other sub-queries, though; the `USING` syntax in particular might be interesting. There are a few examples on that page for `DELETE` queries that look at other tables.